# What does the Refspec HEAD:refs/for/refs/heads/master generated by eGit/ZendStudio 9 mean?

Tags: eclipse, git

Is set up a Project from Git in ZendStudio 9. (basing on eclipse with eGit)

It generates a quiet normal fetch refspec:

```
Remote Fetch Specification  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/original/*
```

But a very mysique push refspec:

```
Remote Push Specification   HEAD:refs/for/refs/heads/master
```

In the remote i can see by "git ls-remote" the following:

```
8db575549dea67a45cea04358f902993c940c4d8        HEAD
16f0939153e6ef12b4596f0d4fb43fa5b8b0246b        refs/for/refs/heads/master
8db575549dea67a45cea04358f902993c940c4d8        refs/heads/master
```

And i have on local machine the message by "git status":

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'original/master' by 5 commits.
```

So, please pay Attention, because my Question is not "What does it means"...

My Question is:

- What does this workflow means? What is the Sense?
- What is this generated Ref on the Server "refs/for.." for?
- Isn't it better to work on a local branch instead of having a ref on the server to push?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `refs/for` is used by folks working with Gerrit Code Review, as can be seen [here](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.5/user-upload.html#push_create).  I'm not sure I understand your last question... you can work on a local branch.  The push spec is probably there to make it easy to submit your code for review.

Comment: OK, but there isn't Gerrit, so it doesn't makes sense, doesn't it? - ZendStudio 9 could have done a normal clone, letting the user chose a push refspec. -> So my Question aims at this point: Is this a usual way to commit, or is it a bad default, worth nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One, a usual Gerrit related refspec should be (as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830065/what-does-the-refspec-headrefs-for-refs-heads-master-generated-by-egit-zendstud#comment19035000_13830065) by [jszakmeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683080/jszakmeister) in "[Gerrit Code Review - Uploading Changes](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.5/user-upload.html#push_create)")

```
HEAD:refs/for/branchname
```

So, if anything, it should have been

```
HEAD:refs/for/master
```

But in your case, you don't need that kind of refspec (since you don't have Gerrit)

> Is this a usual way to commit,

No, it is not.

> is it a bad default, worth nothing?

In your case, yes, it isn't useful.

This could be a side effect of what [this thread](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=73758) mentions:

> Indeed, Gerrit is integrated and shipped together with EGit feature. Currently there is no way to disable Gerrit from within Zend Studio.

The [bug 347077 "Make Gerrit features Optional"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347077) is still open.

---

the [OP tweini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388397/tweini) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830065/what-does-the-refspec-headrefs-for-refs-heads-master-generated-by-egit-zendstud/13834537#comment19105063_13834537):

> To go out of this trap, iI had to realize, that this ref is creating a branch on remote *without a remote tracking branch* associated with it.
>
> But to get rid of it is pretty easy:
>
> - Change push refspec in `.git/config` to `push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`,
> - Push your local repo to remote `git push`
> - Delete the branch on remote `git push --delete origin refs/for/refs/heads/master`

Comment: Thanks for enlightenment, that was the background information i needed.

Comment: Well, to go out of this trap, i had to realize, that this ref is creating a branch on remote without a remote tracking branch associated with it. But to get rid of it is pretty easy: `Change push refspec in .git/config to push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` Push your local repo to remote `git push` Delete the branch on remote `git push --delete origin refs/for/refs/heads/master`

Comment: @tweini interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.