# Git - How to check if anything in refs/for/refs

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit and my default refernces path is refs/heads/.
Someone using Zend Studio is claiming the he pushed something to my repository, but ZS pushes to refs/for/refs/head/master by default.

I tried git ls-remote command, it shows that all references point to refs/heads. How can I check if there is something in refs/for/refs/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in "[What does the Refspec `HEAD:refs/for/refs/heads/master` generated by eGit/ZendStudio 9 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834537/6309)", ZS uses that kind of refs for Gerrit.

To check if commits have been pushed with that kind of refspec, you can use [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222132/6309)):

```
git ls-remote /url/to/your/:company/project.git ./.
```

(if you put `master`, you would see only commits in `xxx/master`: '`./.`' is a more generic template for refs)

Comment: so I used 
git ls-remote gitolite@[my_server]:[my_project].git
and all refs point /refs/heads. So now i can be sure that nothing was pushed to refs/for/refs?

Comment: @ZiomZiomalski because if any commits were pushed to that repo, with any refs (`/refs/xxx` including `/refs/for/yyy`), you would see it with `git ls-remote`. If you don't see any refs with `/refs/for/yyy`, none were pushed.